# Parsing mail address containing Unicode (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, email, python-unicode

The following code:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(b'To: "Ant\xf3nio B" <foo@example.com>')
print(emailutils.get_addresses(msg.get_all('to')))
```

Outputs this:

```
('Ant\xf3nio B', 'foo@example.com')]
```

The name is a bytestring, not unicode.

How to parse the address and get a nice unicode string?

Code needs to run on Python 2.7

Comment: The email code has no way of knowing what encoding the string is in, so it can't know what Unicode character \xf3 is supposed to be.

Comment: If _you_ know that the name is always in latin-1 encoding, you can manually call `.decode('latin-1')` on the resulting bytestring to get Unicode, but Python doesn't know that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Since the application gets developed for the European market, the likelihood of latin-1 encoding is big. But finally it is only guessing.

Comment: Chance of UTF8 is big as well these days. Maybe you can use the "chardet" library to help you guess. But Python can't guess for you.